# opencv cvarrtoMat segfault when deleting original buffer

Tags: opencv

I wanted to convert an IplImage into cv::Mat, all work except a little segfault when trying to delete the original buffer, tought i set the copy flag to true ...

I'm sure i'm doing something wrong, but i don't figure out ...

Here is what I do :

```
IplImage* cvImage =  cvCreateImage( cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3) ;

{... fill cvImage data by mcopy from a blob ...}

cv::Mat mat = cv::cvarrToMat(cvImage, true) ;

if (cvImage)
  delete (cvImage) ;
```

Maybe I misanderstood the copy thing, and only tge cvImage->data can be delete, not the whole object ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in opencv if you create a `IplImage*` with `cvCreateImage` you should not free it with `delete`. try:

```
cvReleaseImage( &cvImage );
```

Because IplImage* is from the C-api you should free them as suggested. You have to do `&cvImage`. You can see that from the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvreleaseimage#releaseimage

Comment: Ooh ok :o I've searched for a cvDelete, and i didn't look well so I missed the cvRelease, my bad. Thanks a lot !